# How to update a value in DB without calling edit method in rails4

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

so I'm trying to update a date field from a page which has `form_for` tag

In db I have a table with one row & one column

So basically I want to update the date field in that first row rather than adding new every time

I am able to do this using 2 different page like:

1. Which has link to edit that particular record
2. To edit value and updates the value in db

Now I don't want to click on edit and then able to update, I want to directly update it right from the first page it self

If I use `form_for` tag in my index.html.erb I'm getting error that `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty` but the same I am able to access from edit.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

Thats because your index and update action has different parameters.

For the update action, you have the model object for `form_for`set. Hence it works. But in index action, it has the list of all records.

You need to iterate over a each model object and create a form for it.

Answer (score 0):

best_in_place gem does exactly what you are trying to achieve